# Sending Message to other process

Tags: c++, windows, messaging

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    const char* cstr = strings[i].c_str();
    swprintf_s(fullCommandLine, L"\"%s\" \"%s\" %S", pathToModule, pathToFile, cstr);
    if(CreateProcess(NULL,
        (LPWSTR)fullCommandLine,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        FALSE,
        0,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &si,
        &pi))
    {
        cout << "succes";
    }
    else cout << "fail";
}
```

I'm creating n procesess to find string in given file like this, and In my module(wchich looks for given string in file) I want to send messages to other n-1 processes to quit

```
while (file >> readout)
{
    if (readout == search)
    {
        cout << "I found string";
        SendMessage(/*what should be here*/);
    }
}
```

From where I could get handles to those other processes?

Comment: That should not compile, you don't pass the right arguments to [`swprintf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx).

Comment: As for your problem, haven't you wonders what the last argument to [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is for? What information it sets in the [`PROCESS_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure? That's a good start anyway.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I just haven't shown whole code, I'll read about this `PROCESS_INFORMATION` thanks.

Comment: Is the other process a window program with message loop? `SendMessage` won't work for example if the other program is console program. You might also look at `TerminateProcess`

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani, yes, SendMessage might not work for a console program but PostThreadMessage will. SendMessage requires a window handle but PostThreadMessage requires a thread id. It is possible to create a window in a console program so it might be possible to create a hidden window in a console program.

Comment: You should use threads instead of processes. No need for inter-process communication, you can use a synchronization primitive or simply a volatile flag to signal shutdown (i.e. `volatile int shutdownPending`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see my [PostThreadMessage to Console Application](http://simplesamples.info/Windows/PostThreadMessage.aspx).

I created that because it certainly is possible to send a message to a console program, we just must make a message loop, just as it is possible to show a window from a console program.

Note that PostThreadMessage needs a thread id, not a process id. Every process also has a thread id and a process's thread id is in the PROCESS_INFORMATION from CreateProcess.

The following is a larger example but easier to use for demonstrating that PostThreadMessage works in console programs. This program will call itself (passing its thread id) if there is no argument for it then it will wait for the new process to send messages. If there is an argument then it will assume the argument is a thread id and send a message to that thread followed by a WM_QUIT.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TCHAR szCmdline[300];
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
    STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    ZeroMemory(&piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    ZeroMemory(&siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    siStartInfo.hStdError = NULL;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = NULL;
    siStartInfo.hStdInput = NULL;

    DWORD dwThread;
    MSG Msg;
    TCHAR ThreadIdBuffer[40];

    // if no argument then execute ourself then wait for a message from that thread
    if (argc == 1) {
        _itot_s(GetCurrentThreadId(), ThreadIdBuffer, 40, 10);
        szCmdline[0] = '"';
        szCmdline[1] = 0;
        _tcscat_s(szCmdline, 300, argv[0]); // ourself
        int n = _tcslen(szCmdline);
        szCmdline[n++] = '"';
        szCmdline[n++] = ' ';
        szCmdline[n++] = 0;
        _tcscat_s(szCmdline, 300, ThreadIdBuffer);  // our thread id
        bSuccess = CreateProcess(argv[0], // execute ourself
            szCmdline,     // command line
            NULL,          // process security attributes 
            NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
            TRUE,          // handles are inherited 
            0,             // creation flags 
            NULL,          // use parent's environment 
            NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
            &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
            &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION 
        if (!bSuccess) {
            std::cout << "Process not started\n";
            return 0;
            }
        std::cout << "Waiting\n";
        // Now wait for the other process to send us a message
        while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, WM_USER)) {
            if (Msg.message == WM_COMMAND)
                std::cout << "WM_COMMAND\n";
            else
                std::cout << "Message: " << Msg.message << '\n';
        }
        std::cout << "End of message loop\n";
        return 0;
    }

    // if there is an argument then assume it is a threadid of another one of us
    std::cout << "Press Enter to send the message\n";
    if (std::wcin.get() != '\n')
        return 0;
    dwThread = _wtoi(argv[1]);
    if (!PostThreadMessage(dwThread, WM_COMMAND, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)0))
        std::cout << GetLastError() << " PostThreadMessage error\n";
    if (!PostThreadMessage(dwThread, WM_QUIT, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)0))
        std::cout << GetLastError() << " PostThreadMessage error\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Why do messages posted by PostThreadMessage disappear?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090930-00/?p=16553)

Comment: @IInspectable, do you consider that to be relevant in some way? I don't see the relevance.

Comment: Since you recommended to use `PostThreadMessage` I posted a link to an article that explains, why and when this API call stops being reliable. I consider this to be relevant in some way.

Comment: @IInspectable, the article says "with a thread that also displays UI". It is warning about UI messages and that is not relevant here. For a window it would be unnecessary to use PostThreadMessage since there would be a window handle.

Comment: *"the article says 'with a thread that also displays UI'"* - Correct. And in a [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677559/sending-message-to-other-process/36688217#comment60965193_36677559) you pointed out, that this is a realistic scenario. *"It is warning about UI messages"* - Not at all. The described issues pertain to **all** messages, windowing message or not.

Comment: Your first link is broken, FYI

Comment: @alias65536 it is fixed. I don't know how and when it happened but the domain name was in the URL twice.