# Windows app access to textboxes in other applications ?

Tags: windows, winapi

I have an idea for a text formatting tool that would be a useful within a number applications.

Is it possible to create an application that would popup when triggered by a hot key or icon click (trigger method not too important) and then give the user options to reformat the text in the active text box of whatever application is active.

I suspect there might be some standard winapi way to do this that would work on many applications but would not work on apps that are using proprietary text box widgets. Is this the case ?

Comment: [c++ - Sending Message to other process - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677559/sending-message-to-other-process/36688217#36688217). Note that you are asking for many things without being specific. I don't know what "this" is in "Is this the case?". Is it text boxes or a popup? Note that you can assign shortcut keys for desktop icons. You can investigate what else can be done with shortcut keys.

Comment: Look into `WM_GETTEXT`/`WM_SETTEXT`. Don't try `GetWindowText`/`SetWindowText` as the `SetWindowText` docs say it fails when setting the text of a control in another application, and suggest directly sending the `WM_SETTEXT` message instead.

Comment: You are looking for UI Automation